# cannot convert lambda expression to type department

Tags: linq, lambda

```
public static IList<NameValueCore> FindDepartment(string search)
{
    return Repository<Department>
          .Find(p =>( p.Name.Contains(search)) &&  ( p.RegistrationEntityType.Id == ((int)Session["SelectMenu"] == 12 ? 1 : (int)Session["SelectMenu"])))
          .Take(40)
          .ToList()
          .Select(p => new NameValueCore(p.Name, p.Id.ToString()))
          .ToList();
}
```

this section generate error: `( p.RegistrationEntityType.Id == ((int)Session["SelectMenu"] == 12 ? 1 : (int)Session["SelectMenu"])`

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Whatever the actual error is (casting error, EF complaint about an invalid operation, missing session variable) it's a *bad* idea to put such code in the query. That expression has nothing to do with the query. Extract it and evaluate in advance and use the resulting menu value

Answer (score 0):

Before operations to check `Session`:

```
public static IList<NameValueCore> FindDepartment(string search)
    {
       int selectMenu = 1;
       if(Session["SelectMenu"]!=null)
       {
          selectMenu=(int)Session["SelectMenu"];
       }

       return Repository<Department>
                          .Find(p =>( p.Name.Contains(search)) &&  ( p.RegistrationEntityType.Id == (selectMenu == 12 ? 1 : selectMenu)))
                          .Take(40)
                          .ToList()
                          .Select(p => new NameValueCore(p.Name, p.Id.ToString()))
                          .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers aren't helpful and are usually downvoted. What did you change? How does this help solve the problem? Please explain why this is a valid answer

Comment: Also note that if that `Repository` hides EF, this query will *also* fail because the ternary operator can't be translated to SQL